# extracting and replacing substring using regex in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, substring, extract

I have this:

```
                                                Title  
Num                                                      
0    <span class="o-label--tiny">VALEUR ÉNERGÉTIQUE</span>   
1         <span class="o-label--tiny">PROTÉINES</span>   
2          <span class="o-label--tiny">GLUCIDES</span> 

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> Num Index(['Title'], dtype='object')
```

This is what I want:

```
            Title  
Num                                                      
0  VALEUR ÉNERGÉTIQUE   
1           PROTÉINES   
2            GLUCIDES
```

This is the regex I developed:

```
(<span class=\"o-label--tiny\">)([a-zA-Z]+\s*\w*)(</span>)
```

Testing it I see it matches the whole initial string and has groups for the different substrings. In the end, I want group(2) in my dataframe column. (My examples below show the explicit regex but I have also tried these with the re.compile result which doesnt work either to get me to the my final result).

This is what I have tried:

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].replace({'<span class=\"o-label--tiny\">': ''}, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

The result:

```
   Title                                                
Num                                                         
0    None  
1    None  
2    None
```

Try number 2:

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace('<span class=\"o-label--tiny\">', repl = '')
```

Result number 2:

```
   Title  
Num                                                         
0     NaN  
1     NaN  
2     NaN
```

Try number 3:

```
df['Title'] = df[lambda df: df.columns[0]].str.extract('(>[a-zA-Z]+\s*\w*)', expand=False)
```

Result 3:

```
   Title  
Num                                                         
0     NaN  
1     NaN  
2     NaN
```

I really dont see what I am doing wrong and any help getting to my desired result would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Title']=df['Title'].str.extract('<span class=\"o-label--tiny\">(.*)</span>',expand=False)
print (df)
                  Title
Num                    
0    VALEUR ÉNERGÉTIQUE
1             PROTÉINES
2              GLUCIDES
```

If possible different `tag`s or `class`es:

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.extract('>(.*)<',expand=False)
print (df)
                  Title
Num                    
0    VALEUR ÉNERGÉTIQUE
1             PROTÉINES
2              GLUCIDES
```

Comment: I was about to add that as a comment. You edited it. I delete my answer

Comment: @jezrael:I tried you code but neither worked for me.  I still got NaN instead of the correct strings. ??

Comment: Could there be something unusual about my strings that I have not considered?

Comment: @ChiChi - I have no idea - is possible send me on my email your real data by pickle file? `df[['Title']].to_pickle('data.pkl')` ?

Comment: @jezrael - yes I will do this.Thanks very much for the offer to look more closely at it

Comment: I send you answer now.

Answer (score 0):

## regex

I don't want to enter in the df thing, but I wish this is useful:

```
import re

stringa = """
0    <span class="o-label--tiny">VALEUR ÉNERGÉTIQUE</span>
1         <span class="o-label--tiny">PROTÉINES</span>
2          <span class="o-label--tiny">GLUCIDES</span>
"""

pattern1 = "[0-9]"
pattern = ">(.*)<"

found = re.findall(pattern1, stringa)
found2 = re.findall(pattern, stringa)

for f in range(len(found)):
    print(found[f] + " " + found2[f])
```

> output

```
0 VALEUR ÉNERGÉTIQUE
1 PROTÉINES
2 GLUCIDES
```